# Cross compile QT 5.0.0 for ARM board

Tags: cross-compiling, embedded-linux

I am cross compiling qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.0.0 for imx53 board but while doing ./configure it is showing "The specified system/compiler is not supported". please provide some solution for that.

Comment: What are you passing as "host", "build" and "target"? Or, even better, post here your ./configure command line

Comment: sudo ./configure -arch arm -xplatform qws/linux-arm-gnueabi-g++ -release -openssl -I /home/administrator/eabi-chroot/usr/include -qt-mouse-tslib -little-endian -no-webkit -no-qt3support -no-cups -no-largefile -optimized-qmake -no-openssl -nomake tools -nomake demo -nomake examples -L /home/administrator/eabi-chroot/usr/lib -L /home/administrator/eabi-chroot/lib -lX11 -lxcb -lXau -lXdmcp -lXext –prefix=/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.5-arm-cross               this is the command which i am passing

Answer (score 0):

It has been a while since I cross compiled Qt... IIRC, `arch` should be the system architecture (linux, or linux-g++). Valid archs should be the one you find in the "mkspec" subdirectory. `host-arch` should be the processor (arm, in your case) instead.

For `xplatform` I would try `qws/linux-arm-g++`, but again I'm not entirely sure; it has been a couple of years and I always end up trying various settings and env variables.

Hope this helps.